# Can I log in to Facebook/Gmail using saved username and password in my android application?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am neophyte in android.
I want to know, is it possible to log in to Facebook or Gmail, onclicklistener of a Button using saved username and password in application?
if yes how it can be done?
I really appreciate any help

Comment: Make more research and write question properly with exact doubt here.

Comment: means you want to log in to facebook or Gmail after pressing button from your appliaction?if yes then use send intent(Action_send)

Comment: @ sandip armal- yes after pressing button from application. my doubt is,  
Is it possible to use Username and password saved in Database/Shared Preferences of application to log in to Facebook

Answer (score 0):

try this code snippet it will open gmail in browser and use your saved username and password

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.gmail.com"));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Is it possible to use Username and password saved in Database/Shared Preferences of application?

Comment: yes it is posible but for that you will have to write another code

Comment: but its not good approach to save user account credential in application
by above code application will use defaul cookie structure

Comment: I can understand it's not a good approach but I have to do this as per requirements. Can you please specify how it can be done?